# Magento2 Elastichsearch showing all products, ignoring pagination & sorting

Tags: elasticsearch, magento2.4.3

I installed a fresh copy of Magento 2.3.4-p1 with the latest Elasticsearch.

I imported products from a 2.3 application and all of the products show on every page, even the search. Pagination is ignored. Filters work when filtering by category, but multiple selections do not work.

Any clue as to what I'm doing wrong or what I may have configured incorrectly?

I ensured to change the path prefix to avoid collision with other projects, but even when I installed this on a fresh VM that never had any Magento application or Elasticsearch installed, the problem still persists.

I'm assuming this may be an issue with my ES configuration but am not sure. Any help to point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I disabled both my Amasty Sorting & Aheadworks layered navigation modules.

I put elasticsearch on a different server, still did not solve the issue.

After re-configuring the elasticsearch server and running this command, everything now works as expected

```
curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/*'
```